# Second time I've been trying to Install Ubuntu on my Mac, I received this and got stuck on this screen

Tags: mac

Here is the error message:

[image: error message]

I did a hard reboot and when I hold opt I see, my mac partition and a partition that says Windows. My Ubuntu Partition is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)